# SyntaxError: missing formal parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I have some errors with my code. Maybe someone could help me. I am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing formal parameter
function col(10,10){
```

And this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function col(<?=$result['seats_count']?>,<?=$result['booked']?>){
       if((<?=$result['seats_count']?>><?=$result['booked']?>))$('.table.table-bordered.booking tbody tr').css("background-color","#f55");
   };
</script>
```

Comment: In the declaration of a function, the parameters must be identifiers, not numbers or any sort of value.

Comment: You should post that as an answer, @Pointy.

Comment: Numbers are not valid identifier names. Simple example: `var 10 = 'foo';` throws a syntax error. Maybe just drop the whole `function col(<?=$result['seats_count']?>,<?=$result['booked']?>){ ... };` part and only keep the body (i.e. the `if` statement).

Comment: Not sure why this was upvoted. Numbers as variables is a commonly known javascript illegality.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly well it's not really clear what the OP is trying to accomplish, so the simple answer to the question won't help much :)

Comment: I will try this suggestion.

Comment: @Felix kling, I tried your suggestion and it works!!! Thank you very much :) Most of the time I like to over complicate the code and then I am getting lost. Thank you one more time!

Answer (score 9):

A [*FormalParameterList*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13) is a comma-separated list of [*Indentifier* tokens](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6).

Identifiers can only begin with an *IdentifierStart*:

> *IdentifierStart ::*
>
> - *UnicodeLetter*
> - **$**
> - **_**
> - **\** *UnicodeEscapeSequence*

Identifiers cannot begin with a number, so `10` is not a valid formal parameter. In creating your `col` function code, your PHP code must produce formal parameter names that each begin with a letter (or one of the other valid beginning characters, as above).

Answer (score 4):

Defining a function and calling it are 2 separate acts:

```
// 1. Define a function
function col(seatsCount, booked) {
    if(seatsCount /*some operator*/ booked) {
         $('.table.table-bordered.booking tbody tr').css("background-color","#f55");
    }
}
// 2. Call the function
col(<?=$result['seats_count']?>, <?=$result['booked']?>);
```

Comment: While it solves the problem I think you should do more than just post the code, at least a one liner of what you're doing should follow. Sure this is fundamental but obviously the OP is missing the fundamental background.

Answer (score 4):

For me this meant I had named a parameter a keyword (in this case "default") so when I renamed it to "default2" then the problem went away...

Answer (score 2):

you cannot pass numbers as function parameters, however you can create a self calling function that will do what you want.

```
(function col(a, b) {
    if(a && b)
    {
        $('.table.table-bordered.booking tbody tr').css("background-color","#f55");
    }
})(<?=$result['seats_count']?>, <?=$result['booked']?>);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kgx7zott/)

Comment: Or you could just write `console.log(1, 2)`.

Comment: I had like so before:
<script type="text/javascript">
    col(<?=$result['seats_count']?>,<?=$result['booked']?>);
</script>

Comment: and then function, but I got a different error, that my function is not defined.

function col(seatsCount,booked){   
   
    if(seatsCount >= booked){
       $('.table.table-bordered.booking tbody tr').css("background-color","#f55");
    }
}

Comment: I I am getting what I need in first code (values), but I cant understand why I am getting error - function is dot defined???

Answer (score 0):

After PHP, this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function col(<?=$result['seats_count']?>,<?=$result['booked']?>){
       if((<?=$result['seats_count']?>,<?=$result['booked']?>))$('.table.table-bordered.booking tbody tr').css("background-color","#f55");
   };

</script>
```

looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function col(10,10){
       if((10,10))$('.table.table-bordered.booking tbody tr').css("background-color","#f55");
   };

</script>
```

It's not really clear what you're trying to do.  It looks like you're using PHP to test the values, and then set a CSS property if they're equal?  If so, you don't need a function, and you can conditionally add the javascript only when it makes sense:

```
<?php
    if($result['seats_count']==$results['booked'] {
        $('.table.table-bordered.booking tbody tr').css("background-color","#f55");
    }
?>
```