# Applying css property in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some errors with my code. Maybe someone could help me. I am getting this error:

> SyntaxError: missing formal parameter: $(this).css("position" , "relative");

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  var count = 0;

  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    count++;
  }

  if (count == 1) {
    $('#box').animate({
      borderSpacing: -90
    }, {
      step: function(now, fx) {
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + ' deg)');
        $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + now + ' deg)');
        $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + ' deg)');
      },
      duration: 'slow'
    }, 'linear');
  } else {
    $('#box').animate({
      height: '10%'
    }, {
      $(this).css("position", "relative");
      $(this).css("margin-top", "100px");
      $(this).css("width", "30%");
      $(this).css("background-color", "tomato");
      $(this).css("margin-left", "20%");
      $(this).css("align-content", "center");
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <div id="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: [SyntaxError: missing formal parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290794/syntaxerror-missing-formal-parameter)

Comment: You miss the anonymous function wrapper, check the doc

Comment: the second argument of `jQuery.fn.animate` should be a function

Comment: Strange error message though. jQuery's API won't be relevant. It is somehow mistaking that argument for a malformed function. Maybe with arrow function syntax, it thinks that's the body and the first argument is the parameter list?

Comment: The second argument to `animate` **can be an options object**, however an object can't contain just jquery objects like that, then it's suddenly brackets with no object key and properties. You probably wanted to put that code inside the callback function

Comment: We can reduce it down to this: `x={ y(42); };` and still get the same error. So I guess it's interpreting the `{` as the start of a function body even though there had been no `function` or `=>`. Otherwise I'd expect an error about there being no property identifier. I wonder why the parser works this way.

Comment: Please, when asking a question, clearly specify what you wanted to achieve and what happened instead (you did the latter, but not the former, requiring some educated guessing from people reading the question).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the API the wrong way, use a function for the second argument of  [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and it will work.

Try this instead:

```
$('#box').animate({
  height: '10%'
}, function() {
  $(this).css("position", "relative");
  $(this).css("margin-top", "100px");
  $(this).css("width", "30%");
  $(this).css("background-color", "tomato");
  $(this).css("margin-left", "20%");
  $(this).css("align-content", "center");
});
```

Comment: are you familiar with this functionality (using JSON like object to set multiple css vars)? `$(this).css({"position": "relative","margin-top":"100px",....});` it would be cleaner - http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

Comment: Actually, [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/mh9wbyde/) would be completely valid, with an object as the second argument, however the OP doesn't have an object, it's just two brackets filled with nonsense.

Comment: I am familiar with it, but my goal was to help resolve the issue not to provide feedback on code improvement as surely this is more for the code review site.

Answer (score 0):

the last argument of jQuery.fn.animate should be a function. if you require one.

```
$(selector).animate({...styles...}, time, easing, function(){ /* callback */})
```

Also as an aside you can set all your css properties at the same time using an object.

```js
$(this).css({
  position: 'relative',
  marginTop: '100px',
  width: '30%',
  backgroundColor: 'tomato',
  marginLeft: '20%',
  alignContent: 'center'
})
```