# JavaScript Syntax Error: Missing Formal Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Anyone know why this error message might be appearing in the console for the code below? I've clicked on the link where it says the issue is and it pulls up this line: " $('tr').each(function() { ".

(This might be a bit more code than needed but I'm not sure where the problem is so I've included it all)

```
function buildData() {
        var data   = {
            "Id": 0,
            "CompanyId": companyId,
            "Date": $('#invoiceDate').val(),
            "Reference": $('#invoiceReference').val(),
            "Description": $('#additionalDetails').val(),
            "DeliveryAddress": {
                "Contact": $('#companyName').val(),
                "Address1": $('#address1').val(),
                "Address2": $('#address2').val(),
                "Address3": $('#address3').val(),
                "Address4": $('#address4').val(),
                "Address5": $('#address5').val(),
                "Postcode": $('#postcode').val()
            },
            "InvoiceAddress": {
                "Contact": $('#companyName').val(),
                "Address1": $('#address1').val(),
                "Address2": $('#address2').val(),
                "Address3": $('#address3').val(),
                "Address4": $('#address4').val(),
                "Address5": $('#address5').val(),
                "Postcode": $('#postcode').val()
            },
            "AllocatedToCredit": true,
            "Comments": "",
            "ContactId": $('#projectSelect').val(),
            "Items": [
                {
                    $('tr').each(function() {
                        "Id": 0,
                        "Number": 0,
                        "Type": 0,
                        "Description": $(this).find('.itemDetailsOutput').val(),
                        "NominalId": $(this).find('.nominalCodeId').val(),
                        "ProductId": 0,
                        "Quantity": $(this).find('.quantityOutput').val(),
                        "UnitPrice": {
                            "BaseValue": $(this).find('.unitPriceOutput').val(),
                            "ForeignValue": 0,
                            "CurrencyId": 0,
                            "BaseFormatString": "",
                            "ForeignFormatString": ""
                        },
                        "TaxCodeId": $('.taxCodeId').val(),
                        "TaxRate": $('.taxRate').val(),
                        "Subtotal": {
                            "BaseValue": $(this).find('.subtotalOutput').val(),
                            "ForeignValue": 0,
                            "CurrencyId": 0,
                            "BaseFormatString": "",
                            "ForeignFormatString": ""
                        },
                        "Tax": {
                            "BaseValue": $(this).find('.taxTotalOutput').val(),
                            "ForeignValue": 0,
                            "CurrencyId": 0,
                            "BaseFormatString": "",
                            "ForeignFormatString": ""
                        },
                        "RechargeableExpenseId": 0,
                        "Comments": "",
                        "DiscountedByItemId": 0,
                        "DiscountedItemId": 0,
                        "AnalysisCodes": [
                            0
                        ],
                        "IndentLine": true,
                        "NominalName": $(this).find('.nominalCodeName').val(),
                        "TaxCodeName":  $(this).find('.taxCodeName').val(),
                        "TimesheetId": 0,
                        "RechargeableEmployeeExpenseId": 0,
                        "TaxOverridden": false,
                        "CisDeductionType": 0,
                        "TransactionId": 0,
                        "Reserved": 0
                    })
                }
            ],
            "InvoiceType": 0,
        }
    }

    function saveInvoice() {
        var data = buildData();
        JA.put("api/" + companyId + "/Invoicing", data, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
    }

    $('#saveInvoice').click(function() {
        saveInvoice();
    })

});
```

Comment: You can't put an `each()` call there. The syntax of an object means the key must be placed there as a keyword or string literal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: missing formal parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290794/syntaxerror-missing-formal-parameter)

Comment: Okay, thanks. So what would be a way around this?

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put an `each()` call in the middle of an object. The syntax of an object means the key must be placed where you are attempting to run the `each()` loop, and the key must be a keyword or string literal.

To fix the problem you can build an array from the `tr` elements first, then supply that as the value of the `Items` property, like this:

```js
var items = $('tr').map(function() {
  return {
    "Id": 0,
    "Number": 0,
    "Type": 0,
    "Description": $(this).find('.itemDetailsOutput').val(),
    "NominalId": $(this).find('.nominalCodeId').val(),
    "ProductId": 0,
    // other properties...
  }
}).get();

var data = {
  // other properties...

  "Items": items,

  // some more properties...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

{}  - means you define "object"
it consists of pairs key: value.

tho you should add key before your each ;)

```
{
  res: $('tr').each( ...
```