# SyntaxError: missing formal parameter with Processing.js, can't find solution

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, processing.js

I have been working on a project called LightningOS (a not real operating system written is ProcessingJS) The source code (when I started running into the error) is [here on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1guSXWnv54tbuulvaFwIXw7c2MP4CiXxr).

Here is what the errors are:

```
SyntaxError: missing format parameter (Images.js:24:16, 'background(0,0,0,0);')
SyntaxError: unexpected token: '(' (LightningOS 0.1.0 Alpha.js:33:18, 'makeNighttimeScene();')
ReferenceError: sketchProc is not defined (LightningOS Alpha.html:26:7, 'shutTimer = 0,')
```

The program still works if I comment the line `makeNighttimeScene();`, but this error remains:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: background is not defined (at Images.js:24)
```

I can't figure out where the errors are coming from, as the lines referred to have correct syntax.

My current browser is Firefox 61.0.1+linuxmint1+tara (error also happens on Google Chrome v68).

Any possible solutions for this? The question [SyntaxError: missing formal parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290794/syntaxerror-missing-formal-parameter) doesn't seem to fix my problem, as its issue was a bad identifier in the function.

Comment: It is telling you the file names and the line numbers within those files,  where the syntax errors are...

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: @KevinWorkman added it.

Comment: @Zackary Sorry to be annoying, but a [mcve] is a small example program that you post directly in your question. You'll probably have to do some debugging to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging, I discovered that the Processing.js functions In Images.js were not being called (which caused the `Uncaught RefrenceError`). If I commented the `background` line, I would get the same error but for `textSize`.

Combining `Images.js` and `LightningOS.js` solved all the errors.

Here's what `LightningOS.js` ended up as after the change:

```
var sketchProc = function (processingInstance) {
    with(processingInstance) {
        size(1366,768);
        frameRate(60);

        /* code from Images.js */

        /* original LightningOS.js code */

    }
};
```